# Ethereum latest transactions

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum

I need to develop a web interface showing the latest transactions in Ethereum and for specific addresses.
I'm using web3 javascript interface but I'm not able to find a way to get the latest transactions.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for **eth_getBlockByNumber** API. In Web3 this call is implemented with getBlock function which implements both eth_getBlockByNumber and eth_getBlockByHash.

The parameters:

1: QUANTITY|TAG - integer of a block number, or the string "earliest", "latest" or "pending", as in the default block parameter.

2: Boolean - If true it returns the full transaction objects, if false only the hashes of the transactions.

"latest" as parameter 1 is what you are looking for.